Identify module with marking 80. B
Please help me to identify the possibly crystal oscillator module indicated by the red arrow in the picture, so that I can search for its datasheet and change it to a lower frequency. I have been able to measure 8MHz - I thought previously it might be 80Mhz.
It appears to be a module with marking 80. B on top.


It's likely not an oscillator, it's likely not a crystal, and it's likely not 80 MHz. It's most likely an 8 MHz ceramic resonator with built-in caps. But I can't help identifying it.

Agree with @Justme - a ceramic resonator. A multiplier code of "B" or "H" may indicate *X100", which gets you 8000. If you assume units of kHz...then 8 MHz. Seems that ceramic resonators top-out about 40 MHz, so 80 MHz is very unlikely. You should be able to find many 8 MHz ceramic resonators, with end-capacitors included.

Might be a Murata CSTCE8M00G52-R0 which is now obsolete.

The markings aren't specified in detail, but when you look at different pictures online, it looks similar to what you describe, the dot position seems to vary though.

(Source: inkocean.in)

(Source: lcsc.com)

(Source: ruitairt.com)

Might be. We cannot be 100% sure it is.
